# Problems with location swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location

i want to make a simple iOS app, using location data. Unfortunately, while testing both on device and simulator, I receive 'nil', even if I enters "Current Location" debug code on simulator. 
It my first time working with CoreLocation on swift 3, so I used the same approach, as I used previously.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    var currentLocation:CLLocation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        updateLabels()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.currentLocation = locations[0]
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func updateLabels() {
        latitudeLabel.text = String(describing: currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)
        longitudeLabel.text = String(describing: currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)
        print(currentLocation)
}

}
```

Of course, I've wrote all necessary Privacy Keys in Info.plist.

When I'm trying to print currentLocation I receives nil. 
With the last launch I found such problem, than an alert is appearing, but immediately dissapears

Comment: What do you mean by "I receive 'nil'"? Please clarify your issue.

Comment: thanks for response. Edited description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` you are saving the `CLLocationManager` in a local variable, but never saving it to your property. Thus, it's falling out of scope and getting deallocated, likely never calling your delegate methods.

Either update your property directly, or when you're done configuring your location manager, make sure to do a `self.locationManager = locationManager`. I'd probably update it directly:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    // updateLabels()
}
```

And then, as rmaddy pointed out, update your labels in `didUpdateLocations`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last, location.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 else { return }

    currentLocation = location
    updateLabels()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `updateLabels` from the wrong place. You need to be calling it from inside the `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations)` method. And since that delegate method may be called on a background thread, be sure you wrap the call to `updateLabels` in the use of `DispatchQueue.main.async`.